# How to configure Apache to send gzipped and chunked encoded response for static content?

Tags: apache, gzip, httpd.conf, chunked-encoding

For the purpose of unit testing, I want to configure Apache to gzip a static file and then chunk encode it and send it as a response. I tried following so far:

```
# Created a file httpd-deflate.conf
# Set to gzip all output
SetOutputFilter DEFLATE

#set compression level
DeflateCompressionLevel 9

# Deflate in chunks
DeflateBufferSize       100
```

Included this file in httpd.conf

```
Include httpd-deflate.conf
```

Send request as follows:

```
GET / HTTP/1.1
Host: test-server
Accept-Encoding: gzip
Connection: Keep-Alive
```

Got following response:

```
HTTP/1.1 200 OK
Date: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 19:24:23 GMT
Server: Apache/2.2.15 (Scientific Linux)
Last-Modified: Wed, 05 Nov 2014 18:17:21 GMT
ETag: "5e28c-5df-5072097390e40"
Accept-Ranges: bytes
Vary: Accept-Encoding
Content-Encoding: gzip
Content-Length: 1186
Connection: close
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8

<binary-data>
```

Is there a way by which Apache can start sending the gziped data in chunked format. I thought DeflateBufferSize can help me do that. However, no luck so far.

Any suggestions?

Thanks.